How to stop a rogue instance of Azure App Service that continues to process messages after deployment?
I'm running an Azure App Service that hosts a Docker container for an ASP.NET Core application. This application uses MassTransit to connect to Azure Service Bus.
After deploying a new version of the app today, I've noticed that the previous instance is still running somewhere and continues to pick up messages from the Azure Service Bus. This behavior is evident in the logs captured by Application Insights.
Configuration details:
App Service Model: Linux Container
Message Broker: Azure Service Bus
Orchestration: MassTransit
App Service Plan: Single instance configuration
Problem:
Despite the deployment of the new container instance, the old instance seems to persist and is actively consuming messages from the Azure Service Bus. This is causing unexpected behavior as both the old and new instances are processing messages simultaneously.
I can see in application insights the cloud_RoleInstance of the roque container running along the current one.
I can also see an active connection to Azure SQL from both the rogue and the current instance.
Question:
Has anyone experienced this?
How can I identify and stop this rogue instance to ensure only the newly deployed instance is active and processing messages?
Is there a way to forcefully terminate the old instance, or is there a configuration in Azure App Service that I might have missed to prevent this from happening?
Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
I have restarted the app service (both normal and advanced restart in the portal)
I have changed the app service plan
I have changed the image (used a stable tag instead of latest)
The rogue instance is still active somewhere consuming messages.

Hi @hrannarorn How you deployed the new version of your Docker container? (e.g., via Azure DevOps, GitHub Actions, Azure CLI, Azure Portal, etc.). Are you using any container orchestration tool like Kubernetes or Docker Compose or a single container deployment?

If you are using compose file other than that please share the files in text format so that we can deep dive into the issue.

Hi @SureshChikkam, we build a docker image in Bitbucket pipelines and push it to Azure Container Registry. In the app service we are using the Continuous deployment option to pull the latest image from ACR.

@SureshChikkam FYI - The rogue instance was eventually stopped somehow but this experience is not very confident.

We are experiencing the exact same thing with up to 4 old instances that keep running.  They are still there and running 20 hours after deploying a new version.  The only way we got rid of them is by scaling up or down so the underlying VM is changed.  This is a showstopper for us...

@SureshChikkam I created a post on the Microsoft forums for this issue. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2005469/old-container-instances-keep-running-in-our-linux)

There was in fact an issue in the disposal of containers that Microsoft fixed on August 27th.  Here's the post confirming it has been fixed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2005469/old-container-instances-keep-running-in-our-linux?comment=question#comment-1777951).
